# Android: display the array of values one after the other according to the button click

Tags: android, arrays, button, onclick

I have an array of 12 integer values and I want to display it one after the other like

Initially on application run I am displaying 6 values.

on the button click I want to display the other 6  values one by one

prevbutton->  **value1**   **value2**   **value3**   **value4**   **value5**   **value6** -> nextbutton

so on **next button** click it should be like this.

next 6 values should be displayed like this

**prevbutton**-> **value2**   **value3**   **value4**   **value5**   **value6**  **value7** -> **nextbutton**

this should be continued up to the 12 values

and reverse should happen in case of **prevbutton.**

Help is always appreciated, Thanks

I am displaying the first 6 values like this

```
     public void autoTune() {
    Log.i("autotune", " called");

    if (frequency[0] == 0.0)
        station1.setText("");
    else
        station1.setText("" + frequency[0]);
    if (frequency[1] == 0.0)
        station2.setText("");
    else
        station2.setText("" + frequency[1]);
    if (frequency[2] == 0.0)
        station3.setText("");
    else
        station3.setText("" + frequency[2]);
    if (frequency[3] == 0.0)
        station4.setText("");
    else
        station4.setText("" + frequency[3]);
    if (frequency[4] == 0.0)
        station5.setText("");
    else
        station5.setText("" + frequency[4]);
    if (frequency[5] == 0.0)
        station6.setText("");
    else
        station6.setText("" + frequency[5]);

}



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("in autotune", " before freq length");
        int[] freq = { 911, 943, 947, 932, 901, 964, 843, 835, 946,904,908,873,877 };
        freqCounter = 0;
        Log.i("in autotune", "after freq length : " + freq.length);
        frequency = new double[freq.length];
        Log.i("in autotune", "after frequency length : " + frequency.length);
        for (int k = 0; k < freq.length; k++) {
            Log.i("In Radio.java", "Freq : " + freq[k]);
            frequency[k] = freq[k];
            frequency[k] = frequency[k] / 10;
            if (frequency[k] == 0.0)
                break;
            freqCounter++;
            Log.i("In Radio.java", "Frequency : " + frequency[k]);
        }
```

I have tried with this code  but this is not working at all

```
  public void forwardtune(){
Button[] buttons = new Button[5];
buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation1);
buttons[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation2);
buttons[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation3);
buttons[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation4);
buttons[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation5);
buttons[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radiostation6);
if(currentlyDisplayingFromPosition + 6 >= arraySize)
       return;

   for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
       buttons[i].setText("");
   }
   for(int i=currentlyDisplayingFromPosition; i<=currentlyDisplayingFromPosition+6; i++){
       if (frequency[i] == 0.0)
           buttons[i].setText("");
        else
            buttons[i].setText("" + frequency[0]);
   }
  }
```

I am calling this function forwardtune() in next button click. still no luck! any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this.

```
int currentlyDisplayingFromPosition = 0;
int arraySize = 12;

public void forwardTune(){
   if(currentlyDisplayingFromPosition + 6 >= arraySize)
       return;

   for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
       textView[i].setText("");
   }
   for(int i=currentlyDisplayingFromPosition; i<=currentlyDisplayingFromPosition+6; i++){
       if (frequency[i] == 0.0)
            textView[i].setText("");
        else
            textView[i].setText("" + frequency[0]);
   }

}
```

similarly you can try for backwardTune() also by reversing the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot  but what is  textView[i]? I have only 6 buttons where I am displaying the values on it. so u want me to have an array of buttons?